# I am getting "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away" when attempting to connect

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to connect to MySQL server on my personal computer (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) from a web browser, using url: http://localhost/Test.php

In Test.php I have the following code:

`$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase", "root", "password");`

I can connect successfully using command line `mysql -u root -p` (and use `USE`, `SELECT`, `UPDATE`...). Mysql service is running.

Any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: Well, you should try connecting to mysql on the command line to see if it's really available or not. That would be the first place I'd start. Then check the logs.

Comment: I did that and it's working. I wrote in my question: I can connect successfully using command line "mysql -u root -p" ...

Comment: try specifying the port ? alternatively try connecting with this : https://gitlab.com/komalbarun/MysqlPdoWrapper ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I just created a new user, example:

CREATE USER 'select_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'select_user'@'localhost';

And changed user "root" to "select_user" in my php code. 
Using user "root" was the problem.